# HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath for website

Tags: asp.net

we had a web application deployed under virtual directory. Now we want to move it to it's own website for SSL configuration.

However, there are lots of `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath` as a result the application is not working as expected.

Could anyone please help me with what's the alternative to `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath` to find root of website?

On virtual directory setup it gives correct path to images whereas on website it just gives

> http://images

which is not good.

Thanks heaps.

Comment: have you tried `Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath` or `ResolveClientUrl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one

```
HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath
```

and alternative

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
```